# MSBuild: How to dereference property by property value?

Tags: testing, msbuild

For testing purposes, I'd like to retrieve the content of a specific property of an MSBuild file, by passing the property name that I am interested in. Let's say, I have a file like this...

Testee.proj:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">    
  <ItemGroup>
      <Foo Include="Bar" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
      <Baz>XYZ</Baz>
  </PropertyGroup>        
</Project>
```

This is what I have so far...

testharness.targets:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(ProjectPath)" />

  <!--Example call: msbuild testharness.targets 
     /p:ProjectPath=Testee.proj;ItemName=Foo;OutputFileName=output.txt
     /target:GetItems
  -->        
  <Target Name="GetItems">     
    <ItemGroup>            
        <_Item Include="@($(ItemName))" />            
    </ItemGroup>        
    <WriteLinesToFile File="$(OutputFileName)" Lines="%(_Item.Identity)" Overwrite="true" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

So, thanks to the quirky @($(ItemName)), I am able to dereference the property value as item name. When executing the example call above, I get a text file with "Bar" as content.
But how to do the same for properties? So I'd like to call something like this:

```
 msbuild testharness.targets  /p:ProjectPath=Testee.proj;PropertyName=Baz;OutputFileName=output.txt /target:GetProperty
```

And as result get a text file containing XYZ.
I would expect $($(PropertyName)) to work, but MSBuild doesn't recognize this.

Comment: You could log a feature request for simple way (e.g. intrinsic property function) to do this on https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild